# How to display per-node memory in TensorBoard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

In another question, someone showed a screenshot of his TensorBoard, displaying memory usage per node:

[image]

I never see those in my experiments with Tensorboard. All I'm doing is calling

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/tensorboard', sess.graph)
```

after `sess.run()`. Are there perhaps some "summaries" that I need to add to record memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instruction [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10317), you might actually have written all necessarry lines for memory and time to be displayed, but you also need to change the "Sessions runs" drop-down in the tensorboard GUI from default "None" to any of the options. Otherwise they are hidden. See graphic:

[image]

At least, this is what I needed to do to display them - the previous answers worked for me, but I needed to change the drop-down.

Comment: I'm going to accept, subject to possible verification in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some `RunOptions` to your `session` run to your summary as explained in this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz) (Runtime statistics section).

Here is the piece of code which allows to do this:

```
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step],
                              feed_dict=...,
                              options=run_options,
                              run_metadata=run_metadata)
writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % i)
writer.add_summary(summary, i)
```

Comment: ... but how much of all that is necessary? Perhaps options=tf.RunOptions(...) is sufficient? etc.

Comment: When I try the above code, `merged == None`, which causes problems in `sess.run`

Comment: It probably means that you haven't defined any summary in your code. You can indeed probably removed the merged/summary part and only keep:
 `_ = sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=...,
                              options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % i)`

Comment: Nope (also, ran into other apparent bugs in TF too)

Answer (score 0):

To get timing and memory info in tensorboard I do this

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()


with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('<path>', sess.graph)

    for (run_iteration...)
       ... = sess.run(....,
                options=run_options, 
                run_metadata=run_metadata
        )

        file_writer.add_run_metadata(
          run_metadata,"run%d" %(run_iteration,),run_iteration)
```